# Does overflow:hidden not work on floats?

Tags: html, css

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/herrturtur/Mem6u/, there is a container div with overflow:hidden, and six contained divs that float left.

Of the six divs, I'd like only three to be visible in #container at any time, and I sized the container and contained divs accordingly.

And yet all six divs are displayed at the same time. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly what you want to do, but:

```
div #container {
   width: 520px;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 1px solid;
}
```

has two problems:

- `div #container` should be `div#container` (or drop the `div`). The way it now is doesn't apply to the `container`, because it doesn't have a `div` anscestor
- `height: 1px solid;` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Why?
Floating elements are not in the flow, parent elements do not know about them. Because of this, they float outside the parent container

you can use the clear fix method to contain the floats ... [clearfix](http://csscreator.com/attributes/containedfloat.php)

Comment: Nope. Floating elements *are* in the flow. They are not constricted to the parent element unless it has an `overflow` setting, but that's not because they are not on the flow.

Comment: "Using the 'float' property, an element can be declared to be outside the normal flow of elements and is then formatted as a block-level element." look at [Floating elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#floating-elements)

Comment: Yes, the elements are outside the *normal* flow, but they are still placed within the flow, and they affect the elements that flow normally. A floating elements doesn't float outside the parent element, but it can extend outside it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use floatet elements, you must also float the parent elements, or they fall together.

Set "#container", "#first" and "#second" also to float:left and your problem is solved.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem wasn't solved by #container float left. I updated the fiddle to reflect your suggestion.